# Laravel: Integrity Constraint violation only on pre-production

Tags: php, laravel

I have been struggling with this for a while and haven't found anything. I hope you can help me.

I have a local environment in Lumen with some databases, and I also have some tests to check the API. In local, everything works fine. I have even checked with several computers, and everything works fine too. The problem is when I upload it to our pre-production environment, where the tests fail.

The pre-production environment is running **PHP 7.3**, **Laravel 6.4.0**, **MySQL 5.7** and **alpine Linux**

This is one of the tests that fail:

```
    public function testUserSearch() {

    $userA = factory(User::class)->create();

    $userB = factory(User::class)->create();

    $url = '/api/users/search?name=' . $userA->name;

    echo $userA;

    $this->actingAs($userA, 'api')->get($url)
        ->assertJsonFragment(['id' => $userA->id])
        ->assertJsonMissing(['id' => $userB->id])
        ->assertStatus(200);

}
```

The User factory:

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => 'password',
        'api_token' => Str::random(60),
        'language' => 'es',
        'role_id' => 1,
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
   ];
```

});

The 'users' table migration:

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('language')->default('es');
        $table->string('place')->nullable();
        $table->string('category')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('checkin_notification')->default(false);
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->default(self::DEFAULT_ROLE);
        $table->rememberToken();

        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

The 'roles' table:

```
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('ident')->unique();
        $table->text('description');
        $table->boolean('active')->defualt(0);
        $table->integer('level')->default(99);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And the error I'm getting:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: role_id = 1. is this value true ?

Comment: It means, roles table doesn't have any rows with id 1. Make sure roles table has data to link the `role_id` foreign key to users table.

Comment: Yes, roles table has a value with id 1, I have checked. I have that because it's the default role I'm using, and it's always the first one I create in the seeder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Role Factory and try this

```
    $factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) use ($factory) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => 'password',
        'api_token' => Str::random(60),
        'language' => 'es',
        'role_id' => $factory->create(Role::class)->id,
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
   ];
```

Comment: I'll try it as soon as I can. Thanks

Comment: great! @GiovanniCabrera